# 'classpath resource does not exist' for .class file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm having an issue with a Spring Boot application I'm developing, building using Maven. I'm pretty new to Java coming from C++ & Go I hope this is down to a lack of knowledge than something fundamentally wrong.

I am developing a suite of applications, which all rely on a set of common classes. I have set up 'common' as its own Maven project, albeit without a 'main' class. I am using VS Code and I am able to successfully import, and run in debug, classes from the 'common' project in my application. I have included a Maven dependency in my pom.xml for the 'common' project and in VS Code debug, everything runs fine. I've then run 'mvn package' in both the application and 'common' directories, building a .jar for each under the /target directory (however building 'common' does complain about the lack of a 'main' class but still outputs a .jar - can I specify it as a library rather than an application?)

However when I run the application .jar with the command 'java -jar configservice-0.0.0.1.jar', I'm given the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class
>   [logsystem.configservice.ConfigServiceApplication]; nested exception
>   is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [logsystem/common/lsrestcontroller/LSRestController.class] cannot be
>   opened because it does not exist

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction on how I could resolve this issue?

Many thanks.

EDIT: Here is the content of ConfigServiceApplication as requested, although quite why this is flagging an issue i'm not sure as the .class isn't referenced in here...

```
package logsystem.configservice;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ConfigServiceApplication {

    //ConfigServiceApplication constructor, called when starting the Spring Boot service
    public ConfigServiceApplication( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Application Loaded" );
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
package logsystem.configservice;

import logsystem.common.lsrestcontroller.LSRestController;
import logsystem.common.connection.HTTPConnection;
import logsystem.configservice.Config;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ConfigServiceController extends LSRestController {
    private Config config;

    //Constructor - initialise storage and create cleanup process for it
    ConfigServiceController( ) {
        super( );

        //some more logic specific to this instance

    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the contents of `ConfigServiceApplication` class?

Comment: Hi, I've attached the ConfigServiceApplication class to the OP, but I'm rather unsure why this is causing an issue?

Comment: Does the code reference `LSRestController` as a resource somewhere? BTW, the constructor of `ConfigServiceApplication` is weird, it should be removed. When the app starts, Spring-boot logs will contain a similar message.

Comment: Hi, that was more put in so I could understand the framework a little bit more and see what code was running where! I'm calling this constructor directly from my main class - its not really required. I do have a class designation which inherits from LSRestController - example attached in OP as EDIT2.

Comment: `@EnableAutoConfiguration` does not make sense on `ConfigServiceController`. It should remain on `ConfigServiceApplication` only. Have you checked that `configservice-0.0.0.1.jar` is "fat" and contains `LSRestController`?

Comment: Hi mate, how would I check this on a compiled .jar?

Comment: ... open it as any other .zip file and check the folders structure?..

Comment: Hi, I've done that and no, it does not include anything from 'common'. Apologies I did not realise I could do that with a jar file :)

Comment: So this means there is something wrong with the project's build: a .jar for a Spring-boot service should include all the dependencies. I'd recommend you to configure and build a simplest app first, ensure that it runs and then add all the necessary stuff gradually.

Comment: I suggest you start the project using the spring initializer found here: https://start.spring.io/

This will create a default running spring boot, maven project for you to start with.

You will see that in this project that there is a maven plugin used, this plugin is run when compiling and creates a so called "fat jar" which is a standalone jar that is including all the dependencies that it needs so you can run the jar standalone.